# ejs not rendering on website - only in source code

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I don't know what the problem is, but when I render a route from an a dynamic get route ("/schools/:school") using res.render("school.ejs") the ejs isn't showing on my website. I actually looked in the source code and it worked, but for whatever reason the page isn't rendering it that way.
for example

```
res.render("school.ejs", {info: "hello})
```

my school.ejs is simply

```
this is the school info
<%= info %>
```

renders the following on the actual website

```
this is the school info
```

but in the source code it correctly shows

```
this is the school info
hello
```

(my server uses express) help much appreciated

Comment: You have missed off the closing speech mark or is that just a typo on here?

Comment: that's a typo on here

Comment: Need more to go on here, is there any output in your browser console?

Comment: alright, my apologies, everything worked it was just displaced by css...